# How to show only desired numbers on a slider?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I have a slider and it's max value is 60. How to show only 10, 25 and 60 as a label ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `setLabelTable` method. Copy-paste from [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html):

```
//Create the slider
JSlider framesPerSecond = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,
                                      FPS_MIN, FPS_MAX, FPS_INIT);
...

//Create the label table
Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
labelTable.put( new Integer( 0 ), new JLabel("Stop") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( FPS_MAX/10 ), new JLabel("Slow") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( FPS_MAX ), new JLabel("Fast") );
framesPerSecond.setLabelTable( labelTable );

framesPerSecond.setPaintLabels(true);
```